# Phaser loading screen animation

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I am working on a simple android app using Phaser. But I was looking if it is possible to create a loading screen that uses a spritesheet animation or programmatically do an animation other than just a simple crop how phaser does it?

```
this.preloadBar = this.add.sprite(50, 170, 'preloaderBar');
this.load.setPreloadSprite(this.preloadBar);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that, i have a boot state where i initialise various game related utilities and the sprite i want to have during the loading screen. Then i just load the preloader state where everything else is being loaded and i just put the previous sprite on the screen. When everything finishes, main game, or menu state starts.
Here is an example:

```
Test.Boot.prototype = {

    init: function () {
      //general game config like scaleManager
    },

    preload: function () {
      this.game.stage.backgroundColor = '#000000';
      // the sprite you want to show during loading
      this.game.load.atlasJSONHash('logo', 'asset/images/hand.png', 'asset/images/hand.json');
    },

    create: function () {
        this.state.start('Preloader');
    }

};
// Preloader.js
Test.Preloader.prototype = {

    preload: function() {
      //add the animation
      this.logo = this.add.sprite(this.world.width/2, this.world.height/2, 'logo');
      this.logo.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
      this.logo.animations.add('shake',[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,17,8,9,8]);
      this.logo.animations.play('shake', 60, true);
      //load all the other assets
      this.game.load.image("hero", "asset/images/hero.png");
      this.game.load.image("clouds", "asset/images/sky3.jpg");
      //this.game.load.image("rope", "asset/images/rope.png");
      this.game.load.atlasJSONHash('items', 'asset/images/items.png', 'asset/images/items.json');
      this.game.load.physics('physicsData', 'asset/images/polygon.json');

    },

    create: function() {
      this.game.stage.backgroundColor = '#1589FF';

      //A simple fade out effect
      this.game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2.0, function() {
          var tween = this.add.tween(this.logo)
              .to({alpha: 0}, 750, Phaser.Easing.Linear.none);

        tween.onComplete.add(function() {
              this.logo.destroy();
              this.startGame();
          }, this);

        tween.start();
      }, this);
    },

    startGame: function() {
        this.state.start('MainMenu');
    },

};
```

There is a video tutorial with similar technique [here](https://gamedevacademy.org/how-to-create-a-loading-screen-in-phaser/) if you want to know more.